# How to Make First Name and Last Name in a same line Checkout Page Shipping Address

Tags: magento2

**Checkout Page Shipping Address**

How to Make First Name and Last Name in the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Try below CSS,

```
#shipping-new-address-form{
             display: flex;
             flex-direction: row;
             flex-wrap: wrap;
             width: 100%;
        }
```

and give first name and last name div width: 50% ( or 49% and 1% left/right padding)
other children div's give 100%.
[image]

Comment: Here is the code for Luma

#shipping-new-address-form{
display: flex!important;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;

}

.field:first-child{
   width:49%;
   padding-right:1%;
}
.field:nth-child(2){
   width:49%;
   padding-left:1%;
}

.field{
   width:100%;
}
// you dont need this line if you target only the first name and last name 
.control .field{
   width:100% !important;
}